# Combine smaller rectangles into larger ones

Tags: algorithm

I have a problem where I need to merge small squares into larger rectangles. Say I have a 2D grid, filled with random 1's and 0's:

```
1 0 1 1 0
1 0 1 1 1
0 1 0 1 1
0 1 0 1 1
0 0 1 0 0
```

The 1's represent areas that are filled, and I draw them to screen way down the line as squares. However, for this problem, I need to match them up into rectangles first. In the example show, the 1's in the top left corner ->

```
1
1
```

can be joined into a rectangle.

I think that should be sufficient to explain what I need. It is preferable, however, that a particular square not be used in more than one rectangle. Also, it does not have to be the best case with the least number of rectangles, just a better case with fewer rectangles. 1x1 rectangles are also allowed were it would make things easier.

Any insight into where I could start, or even a solution will be appreciated.

If you want to know the reason behind this problem, I am working on a level builder for a game I am working on, and I want to reduce my vertex count. I thought I'd start with squares because they would be simple, but even this is boggling my mind.

Thank you for taking time to read!

Comment: Do you want the minimum number of rectangles (hard) or a minimal number (easy)?

Comment: I want to minimize the number only, sorry, forgot to mention that. It does not have to be the best case, just a "better" case

Comment: what I have tried so far just gives me too many overlapping rectangles which would be insufficient. I don't think it's even worth mentioning. I am sitting on the problem more though, so if I think of something better I will update.

Comment: Are rectangles of size 1×1 allowed?

Comment: Then how about this: scan for the first 1, put a 1×1 box around it, then iteratively try to expand the box by 1 step in it's smallest dimension until it can't grow anymore. Remove all 1's the rectangle covers. Repeat until there are no more 1's. It will generate more rectangles due to never overlapping, so there's probably a better way, but I don't know it off the top of my head. For your example, it will generate 1 rectangle too many.

Comment: Cool thanks, I'll try to do something like that. Busy now. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Have you tried asking this on CSTheory too? It's good for algorithmic questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple approach would be to look for adjacent squares and turn them into rectangles.  To do this first go horizontally through the grid and join together horizontally adjacent squares, then go through the grid vertically and join vertically adjacent squares.

Consider:

H = piece of horizontal rectangle

V = piece of vertical rectangle

Your original example of:

```
 1 0 1 1 0
 1 0 1 1 1
 0 1 0 1 1
 0 1 0 1 1
 0 0 1 0 0
```

would turn into:

```
V 0 H H 0
V 0 H H H
0 V 0 H H
0 V 0 H H
0 0 1 0 0
```

This approach is not optimal, but it will turn squares into rectangles if it is possible to do so given the 2D grid.

Comment: I have implemented this algorithm in a much different way then you have suggested. It's so complicated and quite slow. Looking back, your solution is so simple and genius! I think I will change to this. And by the way, I believe your solution IS actually optimal. Actually, I know it is :)

Comment: @Denzil: It's not optimal, but it's quick and it might well be good enough. To see an example where it creates more rectangles than necessary, imagine the following are rows in an array: `110`, `111`, `001`, `001`. This can be covered by 2 rectangles (a 2x2 in the top-left corner and a width-1, height-3 one in the bottom-right) but the above algorithm will produce 3.

Comment: What about analyzing both across and down and checking which one yields less rectangles? Or maybe performing a second and third pass (for larger systems) until no less rectangles can be found?

Answer (score 4):

I'm using 2 steps to reduce the numbers of colliders in my game. Merging horizontally consecutive types, then merging vertically types that have the same width.

[image: steps]

The code is a work in progress, but it seems to be working~

```
public class Tiles
{
    public char Type { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $@"({X}, {Y}, {Width}, {Height}) '{Type}'";
    }
}

public class TilesFromStrings
{
    private List<Tiles> Result = new List<Tiles>();

    public IEnumerable<Tiles> Create(params string[] lines)
    {
        Result.Clear();

        CreateMergedHorizontalTiles(lines);
        MergeVerticallyTilesWithSameWidth();

        return Result.Where(f => f.Height > 0);
    }

    private void MergeVerticallyTilesWithSameWidth()
    {
        foreach (var current in Result)
        {
            foreach (var other in Result)
            {
                if (other.Y + other.Height == current.Y
                        && other.X == current.X
                        && other.Height > 0
                        && current.Height > 0)
                {
                    if (other.Type == current.Type)
                    {
                        if (other.Width == current.Width)
                        {
                            current.Height--;
                            current.Y++;
                            other.Height++;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void CreateMergedHorizontalTiles(string[] tiles)
    {
        Tiles currentRect = null;
        var lastColumnIndex = tiles[0].Length - 1;
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < tiles.Length; rowIndex++)
        {
            for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < tiles[rowIndex].Length; columnIndex++)
            {
                var currentType = tiles[rowIndex][columnIndex];

                if (columnIndex == 0)
                {
                    currentRect = new Tiles
                    {
                        X = columnIndex + 1,
                        Y = rowIndex + 1,
                        Width = 1,
                        Height = 1,
                        Type = currentType
                    };

                    continue;
                }

                if (columnIndex == lastColumnIndex)
                {
                    if (currentRect.Type == currentType)
                    {
                        Result.Add(currentRect);
                        currentRect.Width++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Result.Add(currentRect);
                        currentRect = new Tiles
                        {
                            X = columnIndex + 1,
                            Y = rowIndex + 1,
                            Width = 1,
                            Height = 1,
                            Type = currentType
                        };
                        Result.Add(currentRect);
                    }

                    continue;
                }

                if (currentRect.Type == currentType)
                {
                    currentRect.Width++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Result.Add(currentRect);
                    currentRect = new Tiles
                    {
                        X = columnIndex + 1,
                        Y = rowIndex + 1,
                        Width = 1,
                        Height = 1,
                        Type = currentType
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```